# Experience of sending resx files for translation?

Tags: .net, localization, translation, localizable.strings

We have what is now a sizeable WPF desktop (.Net 6) solution, where we decided from the start to store all strings in resx files in case we were ever asked for localisation. This is now being requested by potential customers, so I was wondering if anyone has experience of sending resx files for translation, merging the changes back in afterwards, and just managing the resx files in general? I can see a few potential pitfalls in this area.

Does anyone use a tool to make this easier? [This one](https://www.hexadigm.com/Index.aspx) ("TranSolution" by Hexadigm) looks very comprehensive and seems to cover all the issues that I can anticipate. It includes a free Excel-like app that the translator is expected to use to input the translated text, but I wonder how much resistance you might get in asking them to use a 3rd-party tool like this.